# Is mutlibit rate option available in Azure media service Video indexer?

Tags: azure, azure-media-services, azure-video-indexer

I am using azure media service Video indexer widget in my application. Is there any option to obtain multi bit rates of video when we upload videos in Video indexer (just like we have in azure media service streaming policy "Predefined_DownloadandClearStreaming").

I have also checked the output asset which is created after video indexing , dose not provide same video  download links as it do while using encoding job on input asset.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@s-tabassum
If the single bitrate is chosen, then we either encode to [H264 Single Bitrate 4x3 SD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/previous/media-services-mes-preset-h264-single-bitrate-4x3-sd) if the video’s height is less than 720, and use [H264 Single Bitrate 720p](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/previous/media-services-mes-preset-h264-single-bitrate-720p) otherwise (>= 720p).
If the adaptive bitrate is chosen, then we use [Content-Aware Encoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/encode-content-aware-concept), which includes layers with a lower resolution.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option for multi-bit rates when uploading a video. Called in Video Indexer "Adaptive bitrate".
You can find it under the 'Advance options'. For more information you can read here:
[streamingPreset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/video-indexer/upload-index-videos#streamingpreset)

[image: When uploading under "Advance options"]

Comment: Thanks @Itai for for answer. I have tried this option, but the asset so created after re indexing , video encodes only in 1280X720 . How can i get further lower bit-rate encoded video?